# Minimum variance portfolio under participation constraint in R cran

Tags: r, optimization, finance, portfolio

I would like to find the minimum variance portfolio for 3 risky assets where the sum of the weights of all assets =  2 and weight of asset1 is set at +1 (i.e the problem would be to  minimise the portfolio vol by adjusting only the weights for asset asset 2 and 3 subject to them not being more than 1 and >=0.  I have found the below snippet of code that minimise the risk for a 3 asset portfolio, but I am unsure about how to incorporate the weight constraints. Any help / suggestions are welcome.

```
 covmat <- matrix(c(3.235343e-02, -3.378191e-03, -1.544574e-05,
                  -3.378191e-03,  8.769166e-03,  1.951734e-06,
                  -1.544574e-05,  1.951734e-06,  2.186799e-06),3,3)

    mat <- rbind(cbind(2*covmat,rep(1, 3)), c(rep(1, 3), 0))
    vec <-  c(rep(0, 3),1)
    smat <-  solve(mat)%*%vec
    smat[1:3,1]
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has a QP (quadratic programming) solver that is designed for these type of problems:

```
library(quadprog)
covmat <- matrix(c(3.235343e-02, -3.378191e-03, -1.544574e-05,
                   -3.378191e-03,  8.769166e-03,  1.951734e-06,
                   -1.544574e-05,  1.951734e-06,  2.186799e-06),3,3)
# linear constraint matrix
A <- rbind(c(1,1,1),diag(3))
# rhs
b <- c(2,1,0,0)
# solve QP model
solve.QP(covmat,dvec=rep(0,3),Amat=t(A),bvec=b,meq=2)$solution
```

Output:

```
[1] 1.0000000 0.3835757 0.6164243
```

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin this is exactely what I was after. I shall look at QP in more details. I really appreciate the time you spent on this.

Comment: The above was for a minimum variance problem. i.e all the returns are assumed to be zero in dvec. Now I would like also to solve for a mean variance problem with the same weights constraints   (i.e asset a = 1 and asset b & c are left to fluctuate without other constraints other than their weights >=0 and  weights a+b+c equal 2) but where the returns of asset a, b & c are respectively (0, 0.1,0.03) . Do i just change the dvec =rep(0,3) with dvec=c(0,0.1,0.03)  ?